# facetime showing a number I didn't call

Tags: icloud, facetime

my iphone facetime audio history shows a number i don't think i could have called.  Absent someone accessing my physical phone, are there reasonable ways this number could show in my history?

Comment: Could you perhaps narrow down what specific ideas are in play here?

Comment: i don't really know to be honest.   it just shows a number that i know i didn't call.  does that help?

Comment: Aah. Let me try to edit it to ask how that happens.

Comment: thank you!  it a number my wife could have called from her phone but no way from mine

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when wanting to chat with someone I accidentally press the FaceTime option instead of a traditional phone call. Perhaps you might have done so at some point? Or maybe it will log if another person attempted to call you (accidentally) and then hung up?

The other possibility is iCloud syncing Call history. Since iMessage and FaceTime don’t affect the carrier - Apple could sync that history if iCloud is signed in on two devices.

Lastly, handoff could also be in play. Again - look at the iCloud accounts on all devices such as Mac and iPad and iPhone.

Comment: its a number i would've never called at all.  meaning not on phone or FT.   turns out it was my wife's secret boyfriend :-(.   so i'm kinda creeped out that it appears i called him on FT 2 months ago...

Comment: That's messed up :/

Comment: yeah, definitely.  on so many levels...